# Observable with buffer and multiple value updates in Java RX?

Tags: java, rx-java

I am new using java RX and I am facing a problem, hopefully someone can give me a clue what Im doing wrong.

The issue:
There are many events I am tracking, such events are triggered like this:

```
Observable<Long> otherObservable = Observable.empty();

public void myMethod(){
Observable<Long> observable1 = Observable.timer(VARIABLE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        final Subscriber<Long> timeSubscriber = new Subscriber<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                // nothing really
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {
                // nothing really
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(final Long number) {
                // Here i do something
            }
        };

        return Observable.merge(timerObservable, otherObservable) 
                .first()
                .subscribe(timeSubscriber);
}
```

So basically it fires an event after a VARIABLE_TIME.

It works great but now I am facing the fact I have too many events.

So I thought about using debounce and buffer.

What Im trying to do is this:

Still create many observables that emit an event after N seconds.

Collect info from each of them (a long or maybe a String)

After a delay time (buffer time) Send a list with all the collected info to the subscriber.

So far Ive done this:

```
Observable<List<Long>> otherObservable = Observable.empty();

otherObservable.debounce(10L, SECONDS).buffer(20L, SECONDS);
Observable<List<Long>> observable1 = Observable.timer(VARIABLE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS).buffer(1);

Subscriber<List<Long> > observerSuscriber = new Subscriber<List<Long>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(final List<Long> ids ) {
             // do something here
            }
        };

Observable.merge(otherObservable, observable1)
                  .first()
                  .subscribe(observerSuscriber);
```

But like this I still get the message instantly after emitted.

I am wondering if there is anyway to do this? Any ideas? I am using java RX 1.2

Answer (score 0):

> After a delay time (buffer time) Send a list with all the collected info to the subscriber.

You answered your own question there! Use the `buffer` operator:

```
Flowable<String> stream = ...
Flowable<List<String>> lists = stream.buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```